# Perl - reading a file

Tags: arrays, perl, file

I would like to read a file into an array. I know a way, but I wanted not to stop my program even if there is no such file. If there is no file, I just wanted to make an internal flag 1 and continue my script. However, I got an error because I do not close the file correctly. Please let me know how to resolve this issue. Any suggestion is appreciated.

My code (ttt.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;


my $flag=1;
my $filename="test.txt";

open ( my $fh, '<', $filename ) or $flag=0;
chomp ( my @input = <$fh> );
close ( $fh );

print $flag;
```

Error message is: readline() on closed filehandle $fh at ./ttt.pl line 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to check that your flag is still 1

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;


my $flag=1;
my $filename="test.txt";

open ( my $fh, '<', $filename ) or $flag=0;
if ($flag == 1){
    chomp ( my @input = <$fh> );
    close ( $fh );
}
print $flag;
```

Comment: ++ because this does work, but it's much better to check for file existence before trying an `open()` if you specifically know the file may not exist.

Comment: @stevieb No, checking for the existence of the file is worse because it creates a race condition. Much better to drop `$flag`, and use `if ( open my $fh, '<', $filename ) { ...; close $fh or die "..." }`

Comment: @cur4so - thank you for your help. Your code is what I wanted to find.

Answer (score 4):

You would typically use the [file test operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html), generalized as `-X`, to see if the file exists before attempting to open it:

```
if (-e $filename) {
    open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die $!;
    # ...
}
```

`-e` might be too broad of a test for your needs; it will return true for plain files, directories, symlinks, etc. If you want to limit your test to only plain files, use `-f` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It is simplest and safest to just try to open the file and skip it if that fails.

We always check for failure anyway (right?), and here you want to keep going. 
So do as usual

```
foreach my $file (@filelist)
{
    open my $fh, '<', $file or do {
        warn "Can't open $file: $!";
        next;
    };

    # process the file

    close $fh or warn "Can't close filehandle: $!";
}
```

This also helps with (possible if rare) race conditions.